# Should we still mine nowadays with CPU/GPU?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, mining-profitability, miner-configuration, mining-theory

For the little bit I understood so far about the mining process, it seems to me that "finding" a block is very very very difficult for a CPU/GPU.

However, since it is done by brute force, it seems to me that there is a very small chance (has anyone calculated how much?) of a single cpu miner to find a block very fast in a few first tries, hence hitting the jackpot of 25 BTC.

Is this theory correct?

Comment: Yes, there is a chance of mining a block with a CPU.  It's ***very*** small.  The calculation is pretty simple and you can see an example [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/52047/5757).

Comment: The "jackpot" is currently 12.5 BTC.   And remember that you pay for electricity (generally around $0.10 per KwH).  The cost of electricity to run your CPU/GPU will be much greater than your chance of making money.   I've never said this before, but you are literally better off playing the lottery than GPU mining.

Comment: @abelenky: Indeed, you are several thousand times better off playing the lottery.  With a lottery ticket you can expect to get maybe 50% of your stake back on average.  For CPU mining it's around 0.01%, if I did my calculation right.

Answer (score 2):

it is now impossible for normal CPU/GPU to mine bitcoin, you need to get some ASICS or Gpus (e.g Rx480) and mine in a pool. of course you should buy devices with high Hashr power to increase your chances to get rewarded. Here is a simulator to check the potential profit you could make by determining your hash power : https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/btc

some details about the mining pool and the network hashrate :

https://btc.com/

Comment: But theoretically can't my miner hit a block instantly by accident in just a few tries and get 25 BTC?

Comment: Yes, it could. But you're much more likely to win a lottery than the chance that that ever happens. Also, it's 12.5 BTC per block since the last halving.